# UmbracoCms ends up with error: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I've installed UmbracoCms 8.5.3 (and tried some older versions as well) package on an Empty ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) in VS 2019 v. 16.4.5. I can install it completely when default SQL CE is selected on installation process. But if I try to install it with SQL Server or Custom connection string database type it ends up with error

> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

I've searched on [Umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.com/forum) and found some similar situations but non of their solutions worked for me (e.g. My SQL connection timeout is 0 (unlimited), I've set `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`, `db_owner` on my database login). I have Orchard core installed in the same VS and SQL instances without any issues.

I've installed both SQL Server 2017 Enterprise and Express (installed it later when I thought it's mandatory to use Express edition!) versions on my machine.

Here is the error part of my log file:

```
{
  "@t": "2020-02-21T10:23:29.1456963Z",
  "@mt": "Exception ({InstanceId}).",
  "@l": "Error",
  "@x": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Foreign key 'FK_umbracoContent_cmsContentType_NodeId' references invalid column 'NodeId' in referenced table 'cmsContentType'.\r\nCould not create constraint or index. See previous errors.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\\projects\\dotnet\\src\\MiniProfiler.Shared\\Data\\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 272\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.<ExecuteNonQuery>b__31_0() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 209\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`1.<Execute>b__0() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 222\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryPolicy.cs:line 172\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.Execute[T](Func`1 f) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 219\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 209\r\n   at NPoco.Database.ExecuteNonQueryHelper(DbCommand cmd)\r\n   at NPoco.Database.NPoco.IDatabaseHelpers.ExecuteNonQueryHelper(DbCommand cmd)\r\n   at NPoco.Database.Execute(String sql, CommandType commandType, Object[] args)\r\n   at NPoco.Database.Execute(Sql Sql)\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseSchemaCreator.CreateTable(Boolean overwrite, Type modelType, DatabaseDataCreator dataCreation) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseSchemaCreator.cs:line 479\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseSchemaCreator.InitializeDatabaseSchema() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseSchemaCreator.cs:line 130\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseBuilder.CreateSchemaAndData(IScope scope) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseBuilder.cs:line 450\r\nClientConnectionId:370d6141-511f-4a7f-894c-e722759915c4\r\nError Number:1770,State:0,Class:16",
  "InstanceId": "6e5d38c7",
  "SourceContext": "Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase",
  "ProcessId": 13248,
  "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
  "ThreadId": 16,
  "AppDomainId": 4,
  "AppDomainAppId": "LMW3SVC3ROOT",
  "MachineName": "My_Machine_Name",
  "Log4NetLevel": "ERROR",
  "HttpRequestNumber": 4,
  "HttpRequestId": "e67f1e83-0f7b-4a05-bc43-eb401576fab9"
} {
  "@t": "2020-02-21T10:23:29.1456963Z",
  "@mt": "Database configuration failed",
  "@l": "Error",
  "@x": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Foreign key 'FK_umbracoContent_cmsContentType_NodeId' references invalid column 'NodeId' in referenced table 'cmsContentType'.\r\nCould not create constraint or index. See previous errors.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\\projects\\dotnet\\src\\MiniProfiler.Shared\\Data\\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 272\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.<ExecuteNonQuery>b__31_0() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 209\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`1.<Execute>b__0() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 222\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryPolicy.cs:line 172\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.Execute[T](Func`1 f) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 219\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Persistence\\FaultHandling\\RetryDbConnection.cs:line 209\r\n   at NPoco.Database.ExecuteNonQueryHelper(DbCommand cmd)\r\n   at NPoco.Database.NPoco.IDatabaseHelpers.ExecuteNonQueryHelper(DbCommand cmd)\r\n   at NPoco.Database.Execute(String sql, CommandType commandType, Object[] args)\r\n   at NPoco.Database.Execute(Sql Sql)\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseSchemaCreator.CreateTable(Boolean overwrite, Type modelType, DatabaseDataCreator dataCreation) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseSchemaCreator.cs:line 479\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseSchemaCreator.InitializeDatabaseSchema() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseSchemaCreator.cs:line 130\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseBuilder.CreateSchemaAndData(IScope scope) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseBuilder.cs:line 450\r\nClientConnectionId:370d6141-511f-4a7f-894c-e722759915c4\r\nError Number:1770,State:0,Class:16",
  "SourceContext": "Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseBuilder",
  "ProcessId": 13248,
  "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
  "ThreadId": 16,
  "AppDomainId": 4,
  "AppDomainAppId": "LMW3SVC3ROOT",
  "MachineName": "My_Machine_Name",
  "Log4NetLevel": "ERROR",
  "HttpRequestNumber": 4,
  "HttpRequestId": "e67f1e83-0f7b-4a05-bc43-eb401576fab9"
} {
  "@t": "2020-02-21T10:23:29.1466970Z",
  "@mt": "The database schema validation produced the following summary: {DbSchemaSummary}",
  "DbSchemaSummary": "The following tables were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:\r\numbracoUser,umbracoNode,cmsContentType,cmsTemplate,umbracoContent,umbracoContentVersion,umbracoMediaVersion,umbracoDocument,cmsDocumentType,umbracoDataType,cmsDictionary,umbracoLanguage,cmsLanguageText,umbracoDomain,umbracoLog,cmsMacro,cmsMacroProperty,cmsMemberType,cmsMember,cmsMember2MemberGroup,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,cmsPropertyType,umbracoPropertyData,umbracoRelationType,umbracoRelation,cmsTags,cmsTagRelationship,cmsContentType2ContentType,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,umbracoServer,umbracoAccess,umbracoAccessRule,umbracoCacheInstruction,umbracoExternalLogin,umbracoRedirectUrl,umbracoLock,umbracoUserGroup,umbracoUser2UserGroup,umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission,umbracoUserGroup2App,umbracoUserStartNode,cmsContentNu,umbracoDocumentVersion,umbracoKeyValue,umbracoUserLogin,umbracoConsent,umbracoAudit,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,umbracoContentSchedule\r\n \r\nThe following columns were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:\r\numbracoUser,id,umbracoUser,userDisabled,umbracoUser,userNoConsole,umbracoUser,userName,umbracoUser,userLogin,umbracoUser,userPassword,umbracoUser,passwordConfig,umbracoUser,userEmail,umbracoUser,userLanguage,umbracoUser,securityStampToken,umbracoUser,failedLoginAttempts,umbracoUser,lastLockoutDate,umbracoUser,lastPasswordChangeDate,umbracoUser,lastLoginDate,umbracoUser,emailConfirmedDate,umbracoUser,invitedDate,umbracoUser,createDate,umbracoUser,updateDate,umbracoUser,avatar,umbracoUser,tourData,umbracoNode,id,umbracoNode,uniqueId,umbracoNode,parentId,umbracoNode,level,umbracoNode,path,umbracoNode,sortOrder,umbracoNode,trashed,umbracoNode,nodeUser,umbracoNode,text,umbracoNode,nodeObjectType,umbracoNode,createDate,cmsContentType,pk,cmsContentType,nodeId,cmsContentType,alias,cmsContentType,icon,cmsContentType,thumbnail,cmsContentType,description,cmsContentType,isContainer,cmsContentType,isElement,cmsContentType,allowAtRoot,cmsContentType,variations,cmsTemplate,pk,cmsTemplate,nodeId,cmsTemplate,alias,umbracoContent,nodeId,umbracoContent,contentTypeId,umbracoContentVersion,id,umbracoContentVersion,nodeId,umbracoContentVersion,versionDate,umbracoContentVersion,userId,umbracoContentVersion,current,umbracoContentVersion,text,umbracoMediaVersion,id,umbracoMediaVersion,path,umbracoDocument,nodeId,umbracoDocument,published,umbracoDocument,edited,cmsDocumentType,contentTypeNodeId,cmsDocumentType,templateNodeId,cmsDocumentType,IsDefault,umbracoDataType,nodeId,umbracoDataType,propertyEditorAlias,umbracoDataType,dbType,umbracoDataType,config,cmsDictionary,pk,cmsDictionary,id,cmsDictionary,parent,cmsDictionary,key,umbracoLanguage,id,umbracoLanguage,languageISOCode,umbracoLanguage,languageCultureName,umbracoLanguage,isDefaultVariantLang,umbracoLanguage,mandatory,umbracoLanguage,fallbackLanguageId,cmsLanguageText,pk,cmsLanguageText,languageId,cmsLanguageText,UniqueId,cmsLanguageText,value,umbracoDomain,id,umbracoDomain,domainDefaultLanguage,umbracoDomain,domainRootStructureID,umbracoDomain,domainName,umbracoLog,id,umbracoLog,userId,umbracoLog,NodeId,umbracoLog,entityType,umbracoLog,Datestamp,umbracoLog,logHeader,umbracoLog,logComment,umbracoLog,parameters,cmsMacro,id,cmsMacro,uniqueId,cmsMacro,macroUseInEditor,cmsMacro,macroRefreshRate,cmsMacro,macroAlias,cmsMacro,macroName,cmsMacro,macroCacheByPage,cmsMacro,macroCachePersonalized,cmsMacro,macroDontRender,cmsMacro,macroSource,cmsMacro,macroType,cmsMacroProperty,id,cmsMacroProperty,uniquePropertyId,cmsMacroProperty,editorAlias,cmsMacroProperty,macro,cmsMacroProperty,macroPropertySortOrder,cmsMacroProperty,macroPropertyAlias,cmsMacroProperty,macroPropertyName,cmsMemberType,pk,cmsMemberType,NodeId,cmsMemberType,propertytypeId,cmsMemberType,memberCanEdit,cmsMemberType,viewOnProfile,cmsMemberType,isSensitive,cmsMember,nodeId,cmsMember,Email,cmsMember,LoginName,cmsMember,Password,cmsMember2MemberGroup,Member,cmsMember2MemberGroup,MemberGroup,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,id,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,contenttypeNodeId,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,text,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,sortorder,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,uniqueID,cmsPropertyType,id,cmsPropertyType,dataTypeId,cmsPropertyType,contentTypeId,cmsPropertyType,propertyTypeGroupId,cmsPropertyType,Alias,cmsPropertyType,Name,cmsPropertyType,sortOrder,cmsPropertyType,mandatory,cmsPropertyType,validationRegExp,cmsPropertyType,Description,cmsPropertyType,variations,cmsPropertyType,UniqueID,umbracoPropertyData,id,umbracoPropertyData,versionId,umbracoPropertyData,propertyTypeId,umbracoPropertyData,languageId,umbracoPropertyData,segment,umbracoPropertyData,intValue,umbracoPropertyData,decimalValue,umbracoPropertyData,dateValue,umbracoPropertyData,varcharValue,umbracoPropertyData,textValue,umbracoRelationType,id,umbracoRelationType,typeUniqueId,umbracoRelationType,dual,umbracoRelationType,parentObjectType,umbracoRelationType,childObjectType,umbracoRelationType,name,umbracoRelationType,alias,umbracoRelation,id,umbracoRelation,parentId,umbracoRelation,childId,umbracoRelation,relType,umbracoRelation,datetime,umbracoRelation,comment,cmsTags,id,cmsTags,group,cmsTags,languageId,cmsTags,tag,cmsTagRelationship,nodeId,cmsTagRelationship,tagId,cmsTagRelationship,propertyTypeId,cmsContentType2ContentType,parentContentTypeId,cmsContentType2ContentType,childContentTypeId,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,Id,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,AllowedId,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,SortOrder,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,userId,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,nodeId,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,action,umbracoServer,id,umbracoServer,address,umbracoServer,computerName,umbracoServer,registeredDate,umbracoServer,lastNotifiedDate,umbracoServer,isActive,umbracoServer,isMaster,umbracoAccess,id,umbracoAccess,nodeId,umbracoAccess,loginNodeId,umbracoAccess,noAccessNodeId,umbracoAccess,createDate,umbracoAccess,updateDate,umbracoAccessRule,id,umbracoAccessRule,accessId,umbracoAccessRule,ruleValue,umbracoAccessRule,ruleType,umbracoAccessRule,createDate,umbracoAccessRule,updateDate,umbracoCacheInstruction,id,umbracoCacheInstruction,utcStamp,umbracoCacheInstruction,jsonInstruction,umbracoCacheInstruction,originated,umbracoCacheInstruction,instructionCount,umbracoExternalLogin,id,umbracoExternalLogin,userId,umbracoExternalLogin,loginProvider,umbracoExternalLogin,providerKey,umbracoExternalLogin,createDate,umbracoRedirectUrl,id,umbracoRedirectUrl,contentKey,umbracoRedirectUrl,createDateUtc,umbracoRedirectUrl,url,umbracoRedirectUrl,culture,umbracoRedirectUrl,urlHash,umbracoLock,id,umbracoLock,value,umbracoLock,name,umbracoUserGroup,id,umbracoUserGroup,userGroupAlias,umbracoUserGroup,userGroupName,umbracoUserGroup,userGroupDefaultPermissions,umbracoUserGroup,createDate,umbracoUserGroup,updateDate,umbracoUserGroup,icon,umbracoUserGroup,startContentId,umbracoUserGroup,startMediaId,umbracoUser2UserGroup,userId,umbracoUser2UserGroup,userGroupId,umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission,userGroupId,umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission,nodeId,umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission,permission,umbracoUserGroup2App,userGroupId,umbracoUserGroup2App,app,umbracoUserStartNode,id,umbracoUserStartNode,userId,umbracoUserStartNode,startNode,umbracoUserStartNode,startNodeType,cmsContentNu,nodeId,cmsContentNu,published,cmsContentNu,data,cmsContentNu,rv,umbracoDocumentVersion,id,umbracoDocumentVersion,templateId,umbracoDocumentVersion,published,umbracoKeyValue,key,umbracoKeyValue,value,umbracoKeyValue,updated,umbracoUserLogin,sessionId,umbracoUserLogin,userId,umbracoUserLogin,loggedInUtc,umbracoUserLogin,lastValidatedUtc,umbracoUserLogin,loggedOutUtc,umbracoUserLogin,ipAddress,umbracoConsent,id,umbracoConsent,current,umbracoConsent,source,umbracoConsent,context,umbracoConsent,action,umbracoConsent,createDate,umbracoConsent,state,umbracoConsent,comment,umbracoAudit,id,umbracoAudit,performingUserId,umbracoAudit,performingDetails,umbracoAudit,performingIp,umbracoAudit,eventDateUtc,umbracoAudit,affectedUserId,umbracoAudit,affectedDetails,umbracoAudit,eventType,umbracoAudit,eventDetails,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,id,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,versionId,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,languageId,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,name,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,date,umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,availableUserId,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,id,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,nodeId,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,languageId,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,edited,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,available,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,published,umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,name,umbracoContentSchedule,id,umbracoContentSchedule,nodeId,umbracoContentSchedule,languageId,umbracoContentSchedule,date,umbracoContentSchedule,action\r\n \r\nThe following constraints (Primary Keys, Foreign Keys and Indexes) were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:\r\nFK_umbracoNode_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoNode_umbracoUser_id,FK_cmsContentType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsTemplate_umbracoNode,FK_umbracoContent_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoContent_cmsContentType_NodeId,FK_umbracoContentVersion_umbracoContent_nodeId,FK_umbracoContentVersion_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoMediaVersion_umbracoContentVersion_id,FK_umbracoDocument_umbracoContent_nodeId,FK_cmsDocumentType_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsDocumentType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsDocumentType_cmsTemplate_nodeId,FK_umbracoDataType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsDictionary_cmsDictionary_id,FK_umbracoLanguage_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_cmsLanguageText_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_cmsLanguageText_cmsDictionary_id,FK_umbracoDomain_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoLog_umbracoUser_id,FK_cmsMacroProperty_cmsMacro_id,FK_cmsMemberType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsMemberType_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsMember_umbracoContent_nodeId,FK_cmsMember2MemberGroup_cmsMember_nodeId,FK_cmsMember2MemberGroup_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsPropertyTypeGroup_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsPropertyType_umbracoDataType_nodeId,FK_cmsPropertyType_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsPropertyType_cmsPropertyTypeGroup_id,FK_umbracoPropertyData_umbracoContentVersion_id,FK_umbracoPropertyData_cmsPropertyType_id,FK_umbracoPropertyData_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_umbracoRelation_umbracoNode,FK_umbracoRelation_umbracoNode1,FK_umbracoRelation_umbracoRelationType_id,FK_cmsTags_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_cmsTagRelationship_cmsContent,FK_cmsTagRelationship_cmsTags_id,FK_cmsTagRelationship_cmsPropertyType,FK_cmsContentType2ContentType_umbracoNode_parent,FK_cmsContentType2ContentType_umbracoNode_child,FK_cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType_cmsContentType,FK_cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType_cmsContentType1,FK_umbracoUser2NodeNotify_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoUser2NodeNotify_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoAccess_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoAccess_umbracoNode_id1,FK_umbracoAccess_umbracoNode_id2,FK_umbracoAccessRule_umbracoAccess_id,FK_umbracoRedirectUrl_umbracoNode_uniqueID,FK_startContentId_umbracoNode_id,FK_startMediaId_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoUser2UserGroup_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoUser2UserGroup_umbracoUserGroup_id,FK_umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission_umbracoUserGroup_id,FK_umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoUserGroup2App_umbracoUserGroup_id,FK_umbracoUserStartNode_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoUserStartNode_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsContentNu_umbracoContent_nodeId,FK_umbracoDocumentVersion_umbracoContentVersion_id,FK_umbracoDocumentVersion_cmsTemplate_nodeId,FK_umbracoUserLogin_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation_umbracoContentVersion_id,FK_umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoDocumentCultureVariation_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoDocumentCultureVariation_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_umbracoContentSchedule_umbracoContent_nodeId,FK_umbracoContentSchedule_umbracoLanguage_id,PK_user,PK_umbracoNode,PK_cmsContentType,PK_cmsTemplate,PK_umbracoContent,PK_umbracoContentVersion,PK_umbracoMediaVersion,PK_umbracoDocument,PK_cmsDocumentType,PK_umbracoDataType,PK_cmsDictionary,PK_umbracoLanguage,PK_cmsLanguageText,PK_umbracoDomain,PK_umbracoLog,PK_cmsMacro,PK_cmsMacroProperty,PK_cmsMemberType,PK_cmsMember,PK_cmsMember2MemberGroup,PK_cmsPropertyTypeGroup,PK_cmsPropertyType,PK_umbracoPropertyData,PK_umbracoRelationType,PK_umbracoRelation,PK_cmsTags,PK_cmsTagRelationship,PK_cmsContentType2ContentType,PK_cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,PK_umbracoUser2NodeNotify,PK_umbracoServer,PK_umbracoAccess,PK_umbracoAccessRule,PK_umbracoCacheInstruction,PK_umbracoExternalLogin,PK_umbracoRedirectUrl,PK_umbracoLock,PK_umbracoUserGroup,PK_user2userGroup,PK_umbracoUserGroup2NodePermission,PK_userGroup2App,PK_userStartNode,PK_cmsContentNu,PK_umbracoDocumentVersion,PK_umbracoKeyValue,PK_umbracoUserLogin,PK_umbracoConsent,PK_umbracoAudit,PK_umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation,PK_umbracoDocumentCultureVariation,PK_umbracoContentSchedule\r\n \r\nThe following indexes were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:\r\nIX_umbracoUser_userLogin,IX_umbracoNode_UniqueId,IX_umbracoNode_ParentId,IX_umbracoNode_Path,IX_umbracoNode_Trashed,IX_umbracoNode_ObjectType,IX_cmsContentType,IX_cmsContentType_icon,IX_cmsTemplate_nodeId,IX_umbracoMediaVersion,IX_umbracoDocument_Published,IX_cmsDictionary_id,IX_cmsDictionary_key,IX_umbracoLanguage_languageISOCode,IX_umbracoLanguage_fallbackLanguageId,IX_umbracoLog,IX_cmsMacro_UniqueId,IX_cmsMacroPropertyAlias,IX_cmsMacroProperty_UniquePropertyId,IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias,IX_cmsMember_LoginName,IX_cmsPropertyTypeGroupUniqueID,IX_cmsPropertyTypeAlias,IX_cmsPropertyTypeUniqueID,IX_umbracoPropertyData_VersionId,IX_umbracoPropertyData_PropertyTypeId,IX_umbracoPropertyData_LanguageId,IX_umbracoPropertyData_Segment,IX_umbracoRelationType_UniqueId,IX_umbracoRelationType_name,IX_umbracoRelationType_alias,IX_umbracoRelation_parentChildType,IX_cmsTags_LanguageId,IX_cmsTags,IX_computerName,IX_umbracoServer_isActive,IX_umbracoAccess_nodeId,IX_umbracoAccessRule,IX_umbracoRedirectUrl,IX_umbracoUserGroup_userGroupAlias,IX_umbracoUserGroup_userGroupName,IX_umbracoUser2NodePermission_nodeId,IX_umbracoUserStartNode_startNodeType,IX_umbracoUserLogin_lastValidatedUtc,IX_umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation_VersionId,IX_umbracoContentVersionCultureVariation_LanguageId,IX_umbracoDocumentCultureVariation_NodeId,IX_umbracoDocumentCultureVariation_LanguageId\r\n \r\n",
  "SourceContext": "Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseBuilder",
  "ProcessId": 13248,
  "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
  "ThreadId": 16,
  "AppDomainId": 4,
  "AppDomainAppId": "LMW3SVC3ROOT",
  "MachineName": "My_Machine_Name",
  "Log4NetLevel": "INFO ",
  "HttpRequestNumber": 4,
  "HttpRequestId": "e67f1e83-0f7b-4a05-bc43-eb401576fab9"
} {
  "@t": "2020-02-21T10:23:29.1476954Z",
  "@mt": "Installation step {Step} failed.",
  "@l": "Error",
  "@x": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()\r\n   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbTransaction.Commit() in C:\\projects\\dotnet\\src\\MiniProfiler.Shared\\Data\\ProfiledDbTransaction.cs:line 45\r\n   at NPoco.Database.CompleteTransaction()\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Scoping.Scope.DisposeLastScope() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Scoping\\Scope.cs:line 388\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Scoping.Scope.Dispose() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Scoping\\Scope.cs:line 363\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseBuilder.CreateSchemaAndData() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseBuilder.cs:line 418\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseInstallStep.ExecuteAsync(Object model) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Web\\Install\\InstallSteps\\DatabaseInstallStep.cs:line 33\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.<ExecuteStepAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Web\\Install\\Controllers\\InstallApiController.cs:line 236\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.<PostPerformInstall>d__11.MoveNext() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Web\\Install\\Controllers\\InstallApiController.cs:line 104",
  "Step": "DatabaseInstall",
  "SourceContext": "Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController",
  "ProcessId": 13248,
  "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
  "ThreadId": 16,
  "AppDomainId": 4,
  "AppDomainAppId": "LMW3SVC3ROOT",
  "MachineName": "My_Machine_Name",
  "Log4NetLevel": "ERROR",
  "HttpRequestNumber": 4,
  "HttpRequestId": "e67f1e83-0f7b-4a05-bc43-eb401576fab9"
} {
  "@t": "2020-02-21T10:23:29.1476954Z",
  "@mt": "{EndMessage} ({Duration}ms) [Timing {TimingId}]",
  "EndMessage": "Step completed",
  "Duration": 375,
  "TimingId": "92b0a88",
  "SourceContext": "Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController",
  "ProcessId": 13248,
  "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
  "ThreadId": 16,
  "AppDomainId": 4,
  "AppDomainAppId": "LMW3SVC3ROOT",
  "MachineName": "My_Machine_Name",
  "Log4NetLevel": "INFO ",
  "HttpRequestNumber": 4,
  "HttpRequestId": "e67f1e83-0f7b-4a05-bc43-eb401576fab9"
} {
  "@t": "2020-02-21T10:23:29.1476954Z",
  "@mt": "An error occurred during installation step {Step}",
  "@l": "Error",
  "@x": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()\r\n   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbTransaction.Commit() in C:\\projects\\dotnet\\src\\MiniProfiler.Shared\\Data\\ProfiledDbTransaction.cs:line 45\r\n   at NPoco.Database.CompleteTransaction()\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Scoping.Scope.DisposeLastScope() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Scoping\\Scope.cs:line 388\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Scoping.Scope.Dispose() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Scoping\\Scope.cs:line 363\r\n   at Umbraco.Core.Migrations.Install.DatabaseBuilder.CreateSchemaAndData() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Core\\Migrations\\Install\\DatabaseBuilder.cs:line 418\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseInstallStep.ExecuteAsync(Object model) in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Web\\Install\\InstallSteps\\DatabaseInstallStep.cs:line 33\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.<ExecuteStepAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Web\\Install\\Controllers\\InstallApiController.cs:line 236\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.<PostPerformInstall>d__11.MoveNext() in d:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Umbraco.Web\\Install\\Controllers\\InstallApiController.cs:line 104",
  "Step": "DatabaseInstall",
  "SourceContext": "Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController",
  "ProcessId": 13248,
  "ProcessName": "iisexpress",
  "ThreadId": 16,
  "AppDomainId": 4,
  "AppDomainAppId": "LMW3SVC3ROOT",
  "MachineName": "My_Machine_Name",
  "Log4NetLevel": "ERROR",
  "HttpRequestNumber": 4,
  "HttpRequestId": "e67f1e83-0f7b-4a05-bc43-eb401576fab9"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couln't find the source of issue, and If someone knows what's wrong in question and how to solve the problem I would appreciate it and mark her/his answer as accepted. But for now here is how I made Umbraco to work in my project:

1. Install Umbraco with SQL Server CE (default option)
2. Convert `Umbraco.sdf` file to `.sql` file using **Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0** and **SQL Server Compact Toolbox (Standalone)** ([Here is how](https://www.geektantra.com/2012/10/umbraco-deployment-exporting-ms-sql-ce-database-to-ms-sql-server-express/)).
3. Create Umbraco SQL Server database then generate tables and their content using the `.sql` file.
4. Replace `ConnectionString` and `DbProviderFactories` in web.config file like below:

.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Server=serveName;Database=dbName;User ID=userId;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exact error during an Umbraco V8 install and was able to fix it by granting db_owner access to the user on the database level. I had done already granted access but this was probably on the wrong level.

**Solution**

Select the database in which the Umbraco Install will be configured and open a new query.

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [username];
```

If you do not yet have a user for the database:

1. Create a SQL Login

```
CREATE LOGIN username
WITH PASSWORD = '<Strong_Password_Goes_Here>';
```

The login should be visible in the file tree under [YOUR-Server-Name]/Security/Logins

2. Create a database user (run a new script on the database in the SQL server)

```
CREATE USER [username]
FROM LOGIN [username]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;
```

3. Grant role permission as shown above.

Run the install again.